# vertical align pseudo element in list navigation

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element, text-alignment

I've created a list style navigation and each hyperlink can be multiple lines, after each hyperlink element I added a pseudo element 'arrow' after, would it be possible to align the pseudo element vertically regardless of the hyperlink height?

The requirement would be for this to work in IE8 & above.

The Mark-up:

```
<ul>
<li>
   <a href="#">
      <h3 class="title">Cover</h3>
      <p class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="current">
   <a href="#">
      <h3 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores cum!</p>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#">
      <h3 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h3>
      <p class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis.</p>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#">
      <h3 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background: #666;
    padding: 5em;
}
ul {
    background: #fff;

    list-style: none;
}
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position relative;
}
.current a {
    border-color: #000;
}
a {
    border-left: 8px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.3;
    padding: .75em;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
a:after {
    content: '>';
    color: #ce4300;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
}
h3 {
    float: left;
    font-size: .875em;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.subtitle {
    color: #555;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    font-size: .875em;
    font-style: itatlic;
}
```

The current prototype: 
http://jsfiddle.net/yVJbL/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
a:after {
    content:'>';
    color: #ce4300;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 0;
    right: 1em;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
}
```

Surprisingly simple :D

Comment: I'm aware of IE8 with this solution... Others can work, right.

Comment: Works in all browsers except early versions of IE I think. Tested in newest versions of all browsers and it seems to work no problem.

Comment: than it's fine, will remember that :-) Everybody is learning, you know. Uped from me.

Comment: I had no clue you could do this until I played with your fiddle a bit. :D Really is simple. Definitely gonna keep this in mind.

Comment: Yeah... setting line-height to 0 is something I never tried. Everytime, I was using attributes like: height: 20px; margin-top: -10px; top: 50%; - but you know, negative margin is really not clear solution :-)

Comment: I have added round cornered border for ::after for list a .. but vertically not coming center..

ul.mtree ul li li a::after {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 16%;
    width: 30px;
}

Answer (score 0):

I thing best solution to make all browsers happy is to use a background-image (this little arrow won't be so big image) and background-position: right center (or so). You are open to hover efect with this solution as well. Background image can be placed also in padding area so there won`t be any overflow.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I would prefer a non image solution because, the arrow color/size would change depending on context. plus would also work fine in a retina resolution.

Comment: Ah, sure... Changing colors should not be problem, resolution not sure. display:table can fix that, however I'm sure it's not supported with IE7 and I'm not sure about supporting with IE8. If display: table, you can setup vertical-align. Last, quite not-straight solution can be using little JS support (understanding that is not nice solution). Will try to think more about it, maybe will find out something.